# Yap.exe DDE error

Tags: miktex2.9, yap

I'm hoping someone could point me to likely misconfiguration of yap.exe.

I just (re)installed MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 for my personal use (i.e. not using admin privileges, since this is a company machine). I can start Yap.exe by right-clicking on a dvi file and choosing the "Open With" option. However if I start yap from the command line, or if I double-click on the dvi file I get "Windows API error 122: The data area passed to a system call is too small." and the file does not open.

To be more precise, if I double click on a dvi file I get the following in the yap.log file...

```
2020-09-14 15:13:28,662-0400 INFO  yap - this is Yap 4.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
2020-09-14 15:13:28,662-0400 INFO  yap - this process (4988) started by 'explorer' with command line: /dde
2020-09-14 15:13:28,727-0400 ERROR yap.core - The data area passed to a system call is too small.

2020-09-14 15:13:28,727-0400 ERROR yap.core - Function: Process32NextW
2020-09-14 15:13:28,727-0400 ERROR yap.core - Result: 122
2020-09-14 15:13:28,727-0400 ERROR yap.core - Data: 
2020-09-14 15:13:28,727-0400 ERROR yap.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp:637
2020-09-14 15:13:28,728-0400 ERROR yap - Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp:637: Windows API error 122: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
()
2020-09-14 15:13:46,577-0400 INFO  yap - this process (4988) finishes with exit code 0
```

but if I use the "Open With" method of invoking yap.exe I get the following in the log file and the file opens properly...

```
2020-09-14 15:16:45,377-0400 INFO  yap - this is Yap 4.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
2020-09-14 15:16:45,377-0400 INFO  yap - this process (16172) started by 'OpenWith' with command line: /dde
2020-09-14 15:16:45,478-0400 INFO  yap - OnDDECommand("[open("C:\Users\sthompson\Desktop\LaTeX\test.dvi")]")
2020-09-14 15:16:45,511-0400 INFO  yap - loading document: C:\Users\sthompson\Desktop\LaTeX\test.dvi
2020-09-14 15:16:52,710-0400 INFO  yap - this process (16172) finishes with exit code 0
2020-09-14 15:24:21,509-0400 INFO  yap - this is Yap 4.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
2020-09-14 15:24:21,509-0400 INFO  yap - this process (5448) started by 'OpenWith' with command line: /dde
2020-09-14 15:24:21,615-0400 INFO  yap - OnDDECommand("[open("C:\Users\sthompson\Desktop\LaTeX\test.dvi")]")
2020-09-14 15:24:21,647-0400 INFO  yap - loading document: C:\Users\sthompson\Desktop\LaTeX\test.dvi
2020-09-14 15:24:26,317-0400 INFO  yap - this process (5448) finishes with exit code 0
```